# Drive Info Not Returned Correctly When Run As A WCF Service

Tags: wcf, service, drive

I have a WCF service that returns the number of local drives reported on my local PC.

I have the following drives:

C: Local Disk
D: DVD Drive
X: Network Drive
Y: Network Drive

When I run the WCF service using the WCF test client I get the correct drive count of 4 drives.

If I try to connect to the WCF service using Silverlight or VB.NET I only get 2 drives returned, the drives X: & Y: (network drives) are missing.

I have a sample of the code below, please can anyone help me with this problem?

```
Dim Info As DriveInfo

Dim Count As Integer

For Each Info In My.Computer.FileSystem.Drives

  Count = My.Computer.FileSystem.Drives.Count 

Next Info
```

Answer (score 1):

When running as a service you don't have access to network drives - this is a rights/permission issue + security measure...